# Define different cases of Android test cases and ios test cases in same application

Tags: manual-testing, mobile, android, testcase, ios

I have to write first time ios app test cases. I don't understand the different cases between android application and ios application of the same application. I know functionality-wise both are the same, which cases are included into the ios application.

Comment: Both would be same.. No change require because you are going to test application not a device..

Comment: Yes, Both Would be same with functionality , but ios and android both are different and my app is also working in different devices..

Comment: I understand but test cases are based on requirement and functionality not based on device. Still if you want to create then you can..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you will be testing on different devices, the test cases should be the same for both operating systems. The test cases should define functionality and expected results given fixed inputs. Although Android and ios are different, I assume you want the application to functionally run the same in both environments.

Answer (score 0):

Even though Test cases might be the same but you need to keep these things in your mind.

The layout of each device could be different. Android phones are available in different layout and sizes. This poses a challenge for the testers to test the application on every possible device. On another hand, Apple has limited device portfolio which can be tested easily.

Different layout and sizes result in a resolution to vary from device to device. Chances are there that android app may not function as intended on all the devices. This means the android app needs to be optimized for each device. This increases the number of scenarios to be tested thus increasing the testing efforts.

Hardware specifications also need to be taken into consideration during. The processor speed and memory play a significant role in certain apps to function smoothly. An application designed for high-end phones might not work with low-end phones.
Hence while testing these points’ needs to be remembered.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are going to test the same application in android and IOS. Then the test case should be exactly the same almost 90 to 95%. Even some test cases may be different based on the size resolution and all the UI aspects with comparing. Mostly in IOS safari browser play the major role so some of the jquery controllers will not load so you have do some focus on that side.**strong text**